# facebook app development

Tags: php, facebook, .htaccess

I have always developed my projects using MAMP locally and once done simply uploaded everything to a live server. However, I'm wanting to integrate some FB functionality in my current project and I believe I'm correct in saying that it is not possible to fully test FB integration locally. My problem is I don't want to release the project I'm working on until it's finished (or at least nearly finished!) by placing it on a live server. I don't even want people to see a login screen or anything. Is there a way I can upload everything to my domain for testing purposes but prevent anyone apart from me from accessing the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to test almost everything (with quite rare exclusions) related to FB locally.

The only exceptions I can recall are:

1. Attachments to stream messages
2. Subscriptions

Btw, if there are another issues I forgot and you're experiencing - you can create test domain with such `.htaccess` in its root:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
AuthName "Password"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

Allow from 69.63.176.0/20
Satisfy Any
```

Where `69.63.176.0/20` equals to `69.63.176.0 - 69.63.191.255` and belongs to facebook and `.htpasswd` is a password file created with console utility `htpasswd`

```
htpasswd -c /path/to/.htpasswd musoNic80 // and enter password after
```

With such `.htaccess` everyone except of someone with facebook IP will be required to enter valid login/pass trough basic http auth.

Also, if you have dynamic but your own IP (given to only you once you logged in your pppoe (or whatever you use) session, and changes after you re-logged in) - you could use `http://no-ip.org` and have your local host to be shared outside, and available for facebook thus.

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough answer. I will certainly try again with testing fb locally - with a little googling I discovered it might work using a local ip address instead of a URL. But if I can't get it to work then i'll go with one of your other suggestions! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's super simple, check out localtunnel and plug in the url to facebook. This will expose your computer to the net in a very limited way and will shut the tunnel when you chose to.

http://progrium.com/localtunnel/

I'm not sure if this works on Windows but I'm sure there's something similar.