# Why does this code throw a Facebook API Error 191?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the following config.php file  sitting at www.sitename.com/facebook/

```
<?php
  require_once 'library/facebook.php';
  $app_id = "xyz";
  $app_secret ="xyz"
  $facebook = new Facebook(array (
    'appId' => $app_id,
    'secret'=> $app_secret,
    'cookie'=> true
  ));
  if(is_null ($facebook->getUser()))
  {
    header("Location:{$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms'=>'user_status, publish_stream, user_photos'))}");
    exit;
  }
?>
```

The site URL used in registering the app is http://www.sitename.com/facebook/

so running this file should direct me to an authorization page...instead i get the following error:

```
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.
```

Can any one explain how to get around this and why this happens?

Comment: What is `redirect_uri` being set to?

Comment: I believe it is set to the currentURL (i.e. mysite.com/facebook/) by the getLoginUrl method  in the facebook PHP-SDK so don't see the cause of the problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook API error 191](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191)

Answer (score 1):

Reason for error 191:

In Facebook Application Setting, Site URL is not same as REQUEST_URI (Redirecting URL)
e.g., 
if you specified site URL to `http://www.sitename.com/facebook/` then you are not allow to redirect to `http://www.namesite.com/facebook/`