# Error Code 191 and RFC 3986

Tags: facebook, codeigniter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does this code throw a Facebook API Error 191?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571382/why-does-this-code-throw-a-facebook-api-error-191)

```
An error occurred with Dean Mobile (My Mobile App). Please try again later.
```

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri isn't an absolute URI. Check RFC 3986.

What does this mean?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571382/why-does-this-code-throw-a-facebook-api-error-191 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382621/facebook-api-error-code-191 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409532/api-error-code-191 etc

Answer (score 0):

What's your redirect URL? is it a relative URL like the error messages suggests?

If so, it needs to be an absolute URL (e.g. 'http://blah.com/something' instead of '/something/)