# Facebook integration error 191 - how to fix

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have created a Facebook application and am using the API details to get the application integrated with Facebook. However, I get the following error when I click on `Login`:

> API Error Code: 191 API Error
>   Description: The specified URL is not
>   owned by the application 
>   Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by
>   the application.

Why am I getting this error and how can I correct it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook API error 191](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191)

Answer (score 2):

there is a setting in your application settings under the "web site" tab that says: "website URL". There must be a match between this an your redirect_uri (at least at the domain-level).

Comment: I checked it still no use... This is the URL I get when I click on Login, https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?api_key=........anyting to do with permission settings, plz suggest.

Comment: Can you update your post with the actual URL you are using to login (minus your app-key, etc)

Comment: this is the code what I have written....$facebook = new Facebook(array( 'appId'  => FACEBOOK_APP_ID, 'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY, 'cookie' => true));   
$session = $facebook->getSession();   
if ($session) {   
 try {   
  $uid = $facebook->getUser(); 
  $me = $facebook->api('/me');   
  $updated = date("l, F j, Y", strtotime($me['updated_time']));   
  echo "Hello " . $me['name'] . "<br />"; 
  echo "You last updated your profile on " . $updated;   
 } 
 catch (FacebookApiException $e) {   
  echo "Error:" . print_r($e, true);   
 } 
}