# Facebook Connect API error 191 with Django-socialregistration

Tags: python, django, facebook

I have seen error 191 all over the web and know it has something to do with there being something wrong with the configuration of the app.

However I have not found an answer to most of the questions and also none that help me.

My app on Facebook is setup like this:

**Site URL** http://example.com/

**Site Domain** example.com

( Forgive me for not sharing the real url but I am not a liberty to as of yet. )

What I get when I click the Connect with Facebook button is

```
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.
```

I have changed the site url in the admin sections to the site url as well, Something with was troubling the Twitter sign-in part off the app.

I have followed all of the instructions on the [Django-SocialRegistration site](https://github.com/flashingpumpkin/django-socialregistration) and can see no error in what I have done.

Has anyone else had this and fixed it?

**EDIT**

In this particular case it seems its was a problem with Facebook.

As I logged on tonight I noticed that there was multiple instances of my app, each with older versions of settings. They were not visible before now.

However I will be jumping ship to [django-social-auth.](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) It looks better documented and easier to configure and use.

Sorry this isnt the best answer!

Comment: Seems like an obvious question, but are you using a subdomain or redirecting in any way? Also, could it possibly be a registration issue on FB's end?

Comment: Also, are you developing this locally (because your URL and domain settings will need to reflect this), or on the actual production server/domain? Also, what is your canvas setting?

Comment: I am hoping it is obvious to be honest,
I am not using a subdomain or redirecting afaik, you would have to suggest where the bad redirection would be coming from

Comment: The domain is pointed to my home router address with is configured to NAT traffic to my Django test server. I didn't want to mess with getting my server ready just yet. Either way I don't think this is it because the urls are the same as the ones on FB

Comment: I am not using canvas afaik, I am new to using the FB API's I just want to use it for Auth. I also see no canvas setting on the FB app settings page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook API error 191](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191)

Comment: nothing to do with Django-socialregistration, only related to facebook app settings!

Answer (score 0):

Plz check the redirect Uri, while taking permisiion from user.