# Getting Facebook API Error Code 191, but only in Internet Explorer

Tags: php, facebook, yii

I'm seeing this error in Internet Explorer (but not other browsers):

> API Error Code: 191
>   API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
>   Error Message: redirect_uri isn't an absolute URI. Check RFC 3986.

My canvas URL is `http://nintriva.com/_others/groupbuy/index.php?r=groupbuy/facebook/authenticate` and my app is installed on the page `http://www.facebook.com/nintriva?sk=app_241476069209769`.

I have provided the site URL, `http://www.nintriva.com/_others/groupbuy/index.php?r=groupbuy/facebook/authenticate`, and the site domain `www.nintriva.com`.

I use this code to redirect to the Facebook fan page after the user gives permission:

```
$this->auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=".Yii::app()->controller->module->app_id."&redirect_uri=".urlencode($session['page_link']."?sk=app_".Yii::app()->controller->module->app_id)."&scope=email,user_location";
```

where `page_link` is the user fan page link I get from a signed request.

Comment: try removing the `www.` from your **Site Domain** so it looks like:  `nintriva.com`

Comment: Also do you have a DNS or 301 redirect for www traffic to non-www or the other way around? if not then `http://www.nintriva.com/_others/...` and `http://nintriva.com/_others/....` will be treated differently I suppose.

Comment: i tried without www.but no use

Comment: i have used this code to redirect to the facebook fan page after user allow permission.

Comment: its an auth url to get permission from user to access basic info and email.in that i have used redirect_uri=page_link?sk=app_id on it to redirect to user's fan page after allow permission and it works for me in evry browser but not in IE.

Comment: can you paste what is inside `$session['page_link']`?

Comment: $this->auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=".Yii::app()->controller->module->app_id."&redirect_uri=".urlencode($session['page_link']."?sk=app_".Yii::app()->controller->module->app_id)."&scope=email,user_location";

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook API error 191](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, Facebook sees URLs http://www.example.com as different from http://example.com

for the Facebook lo-gin to work you, your URLs must be exactly the way it is at Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you got that error because the URL is constructed dynamically and it needs to be static.