# Getting a 191 error as a result of facebook's API keys and API IDs being combined

Tags: facebook, api, api-key

Back in June, Facebook used to display a set of keys on the application settings page: the API key and the API ID. These were different than each other. At that time, my partner and I wrote a Facebook app in PHP, passing the two keys to substantiated the facebook class. We saved the keys to a config file.

However, these two keys are now one and the same, and as a result, I'm getting error 191. We have not changed the code or settings since June. While doesn't this affect our current applications, where the API key is unique, it does prevent us from making new applications using the existing code base.

What can we do to resolve this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook API error 191](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191)

Answer (score 1):

Anywhere in the API which used the API key can also use the App ID, they're treated identically in the backend code. 
Error 191 is an error about trying to redirect the user  during the login process to a URL not owned by your application so check what URL you're setting in the 'next' or 'redirect_uri' parameter when sending the user to the login / authorisation dialog