# Facebook API - What should the redirect URL be for a desktop/native application?

Tags: facebook

I am developing a desktop application that will interface with FB. FB insists that you provide a Site URL. Since this is a desktop application this doesn't really make sense. I set the site url to 'localhost'.

I just get the following error when I put 'localhost' in the url string

> API Error Code: 191 API Error Description: The specified URL is not
>   owned by the application Error Message: redirect_uri isn't an absolute
>   URI. Check RFC 3986.

This looks like a pretty common error but I don't see any examples of how desktop applications should handle this site url requirement.

Can someone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook API error 191](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pays to read the documentation to the end :)

> Our OAuth 2.0 implementation does not include explicit desktop app
>   support. However, if your desktop app can embed a web browser (most
>   desktop frameworks such as .NET, AIR and Cocoa support embedding
>   browsers), you can use the client-side flow with one modification: a
>   specific redirect_uri. Rather than requiring desktop apps to host a
>   web server and populate the Site URL in the Developer App, we provide
>   a specific URL you can use with desktop apps:
>   https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html.

Comment: Thank you for answering your own question. This was helpful.