# Facebook API error code 191

Tags: facebook, api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook API error 191](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191)

I'm developing a Facebook app. When I attempt to get an access token, I get the following message:

> An error occurred with test. Please try again later.
>
> API Error Code: 191
>   API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
>   Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/.../summary

I've configured the app's domain (`appsdot.xxx.com`), name and other attributes.

What is causing this error, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The redirect_uri must contain the Site URL or Canvas URL as defined in your App Settings.  I always get this error when I set a redirect_uri that doesn't contain the URLs in App Settings.

Comment: what if i have an iframe app loaded in a fanpage's tab? should i use the page tab url value, right?

Comment: i think you mean redirect_uri, not redirect_url

Comment: Thanks @Luc. I updated my answer with the correction.

Answer (score 4):

I got this error because I had a trailing slash on my Canvas URL and neglected to include the trailing slash in the redirect_uri.

Comment: This was also the solution for me - both the URL as set in the Page URL settings and the YOUR_URL (as per: http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL) need to contain a trailing slash

Answer (score 0):

be carefull  error is about uri (i spell: Uniform Romeo India) and the most probably you are using word url (i spell: Uniform Romeo Lima)   ... do you see the difference???

just add st like this:

redirect_uri: 'YOUR_PAGE_TAB_URL OR CANVAS_URL'

how simple,isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was happening because I didn't configure the site domain in the right way.

You can access your site model by the admin and change the domain name from `example.com` to the real domain that you are using.

The best way to fix this is create a fixture; something like:

`YOUR_APP/initial_data.json`:

```
[{"pk": 1, "model": "sites.site", "fields":
 {"domain": "127.0.0.1:8000", "name": "127.0.0.1:8000"}
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

this just because of URL mistake

whatever website url is specified should be correct.

i mentioned website url as http://localhost:3000/ and domain as localhost

but in my browser i was running http://0.0.0.0:3000/ that was the actual problem so i ran server as localhost:3000 now its working fine. Because we mentioned site url as localhost fb will redirect to same, if we r running 0.0.0.0:3000 it will rise error that Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.

so becarefull with your website url you have specified in facebook app.
and the url you are running locally both should match

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your domain is not being masked.

Answer (score -1):

The base_url must contain the Site URL or Canvas URL as defined in your App Settings. I always get this error when I set a redirect_url that doesn't contain the URLs in App Settings.

Answer (score -1):

You do have to register/create the url with facebook, by creating a facebook app. You might have to give the mobile phone number to them. The Site url you put in there needs to passed as the redirect url.

Answer (score -2):

rails#{This error is related to URL}

-I just put the ip address in all the URL instead of localhost..now it's working file before doing that I tried so many things but didn't work..I am sure this one will work..