# Facebook authentication API

Tags: facebook, url, authentication, uri

I'm new to facebook API and I have some questions related to facebook authentication.
I have created an application and have edited the domain and url.

> Website Domain
>   giftme.web44.net
>   Site URL
>   http://www.giftme.web44.net/

I used the following on my site webpage:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '3347207XXXXXXXX', // App ID (I've replaced for security reasons)
        channelUrl : 'http://giftme.web44.net/channel.html/', // Channel File
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
      });
      // Additional initialization code here
    };
    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
     }(document));
  </script>
```

And I've created the page 'channel.html' with only this:

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

Finally I used the login button:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" >Login with Facebook</div>
```

What i'm I doing wrong?
I keep getting this error:

> API Error Code: 191
>   API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
>   Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: A URL informada não é permitida pela configuração do aplicativo.

Answer (score 1):

`http://www.giftme.web44.net/` is not equal to `http://giftme.web44.net/`

Answer (score 0):

The redirect_url must contain the Site URL or Canvas URL as defined in your App Properties.

An example would be:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/admin.setAppProperties?
  access_token=CURRENTTOKEN&
  properties={'post_authorize_redirect_url':'http://giftme.web44.net/channel.html/'}
```

[Error code 191](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382621/facebook-api-error-code-191)
[FB App Properties](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appproperties/)

Comment: where can i define redirect_url ?

Comment: Where can I find the redirect_uri? Or do I have to add it to the script?
I need to set the canvas url?