# Error when login with a Facebook app

Tags: php, facebook-apps

I am trying to develop a fb app. It shows me a error message when I try to log in with the app.

> API Error Code: 191
>   API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
>   Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.

```
app domain:www.abc.def.com

site url :http://www.abc.def.com/

Canvas URL:http://www.abc.def/fbapp/
```

Comment: www.abc.def doesn't appear to be a valid URL.

Comment: www.abc.def.com would be a valid URL, like www.sub.example.com. So, www.abc.def would be as www.sub.example, which is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your redirect_url

The redirect_url must contain the Site URL or Canvas URL as defined in your App Settings. If one has a trailing slash the other must too.

You will find that this is the most common solution to this problem.

[Facebook API error code 191](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382621/facebook-api-error-code-191)
also
[Facebook API error 191](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191)