# Facebook Actionscript API Login

Tags: ios, facebook, actionscript-3, authentication

I am currently having problems using a WebView with this API to login to my app. I feel like I've set up something wrong somewhere, but can't put my finger on it.

Here's the error I'm getting :

Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration code:191

I've set up my application descriptor like this (the x's are my app id)

```
        <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
        <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                <array>
                    <string>fbxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</string>
```

I don't know if I need to add a setting in my facebook app page, but I've enabled embedded browser login and that's it.

Am I forgetting something here ?

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be caused by many things. I've used this and it helped me a lot:
http://afterisk.wordpress.com/2013/02/26/first-free-facebook-single-sign-on-sso-adobe-air-native-extension-for-android/

It important to follow almost every step as there are multiple properties in Facebook that you must set.

Second, check this SO: [Facebook API error code 191](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382621/facebook-api-error-code-191)
I don't know what's the url that you open - it's best to get it as login url from FB.

I hope that helps and will solve your problem :)