# API Error Code: 191

Tags: facebook, api, oauth-2.0

yep, getting the 191 error.
I've researched and found this question to be helpful:
[Facebook API error 191](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191)

My URL looks like:

> https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=&redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%2fFb.201109Birthday%2fOAuth2.aspx

However, I get an error:

> API Error Code: 191 API Error Description: The specified URL is not
>   owned by the application Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given
>   URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.

I've read everywhere that the urls must match up to what's listed in the application's setting page.  I've got

- App Domain = localhost
- Canvas Url = http://localhost/Fb.201109Birthday/Birthday.aspx?
- Secure Canvas Url = http://localhost/Fb.201109Birthday/Birthday.aspx?

I've also tried local.facebook-apps.com (replaced "localhost" everywhere above with "local.facebook-apps.com") with a hosts file entry to point to 127.0.0.1.  But all of these scenarios still give the 191.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook API error 191](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the Birthday.aspx from the Canvas URLs.

Comment: That was it!  Thanks a tonne.  :)

Comment: Please don't ask new questions in comments, @Enrique. Very few people will see them, and there's no good way for people who do see them to respond. Ask a new question of your own instead!

Answer (score 3):

I was also getting this error when i created a facebook application that was going to be installed onto a tab on a fan page. It turns out that when i first created my facebook application i only filled out the section for "Page Tab" but i didn't fill out the section for "App on Facebook".

i didn't fill out the App on Facebook section because i didn't want users trying to add the app from the app profile page. Anyway, it turns out that by not filling out the App on Facebook section and adding a `canvas URL` and `secure canvas URL` i was getting the `Error: 191` when trying to make a javascript call to `FB.Login()`.

Once i filled out the App on Facebook section the error went away.

Answer (score 1):

Filling up the "App on Facebook" page, with Canvas url, ended with /
solvet it for me

ex: canvas [url](http://myurl.com/).

Answer (score 1):

above issue can be removed via providing the URL for the web site or localhost you are working on, at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ under Edit-->Website with Facebook Login

[image: Website with Facebook Login]

Answer (score -1):

Web forwarding occurs 191 problem.

I used web forwarding for app's domain.

I had problem 191 and solved by fixing original url.