# App page tab will not add to business page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-page

I am trying to add an app to my page.

Ive tried:
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=####&next=http://www.facebook.com/evendark
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=####&next=www.facebook.com/evendark

I get

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.

What am I doing wrong?  this always worked before and thats all any of the search sites do.  All I want is an iframe displayed as a tab.  Thats all.  Nothing fancy.  I know the ID I am using is the right one Ivee done this before.  UGH!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook API error 191](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191)

Answer (score 1):

After you have set the `Site URL` in Facebook Settings,
you can add this url in the `redirect_uri` parameter.

**Similar questions:**
[Facebook API error 191](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191)
[API Error Code: 191](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409532/api-error-code-191)
[Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453683/invalid-redirect-uri-given-url-is-not-allowed-by-the-application-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

to add an app page tab to a page, try using js sdk with the following.  NOTE:  you will need to goto the page and add manually from admin settings under applications.

**refer to:** https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

---

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
<button onclick="addToPage();">Add Tab to Page</button>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>   
<script> 
      function addToPage() {
        // calling the API ...
        var obj = {
          method: 'pagetab',
          redirect_uri: 'http://anotherfeed.com/',
        };

        FB.ui(obj);
      }

    </script>
```

Comment: I have never done a script in facebook before.  Where do I go from the dashboard to get to that?

Comment: is is a full sample, see refer to: for more info on javascript sdk.

Comment: I just don't know how to get into the facebook area for the java on the app page - I can edit the page of mine.  Where is this?  From the app dashboard?

Comment: i am sorry Julie, i was refering to an external website. I just realized you are trying to modify Facebook itself on the site, you can not do that at this time.
http://anotherfeed.com  at top left by logo is Add! button.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

The `redirect_uri` parameter must be the url where the iFrame is hosted. In my case, setting the variable to the facebook app url returned an error.

I had to delete the tab, and then set it again to the iframe page, i.e. www.domain.com/iframe.php.

One detail, I initially created the iframe page as a static page, i.e. iframe.htm, which led the tab to display an error message 'incorrect function', since these pages MUST be served by a dynamic page server, such as ASP or PHP.