# API Error code 191

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Facebook API error 191](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191)

> API Error Code: 191
>
> API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
> Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.

What's wrong?

Comment: are you trying it in local ??

Answer (score 1):

When you register for an application at Facebook you must provide the domain which would be using this application.

So if you have created an application which says "abc.com" then that application can only be called "abc.com". So when you try calling your application from "xyz.com" it gets rejected with the mentioned error.

Comment: Thanks for the info , but is it possible to that user can use abc.com and www.abc.com at the same time for facebook login

Comment: I think abc.com is the same as www.abc.com .. can be wrong though

Comment: facebook differentiate those , so i got to redirect it

Comment: I don't think that would be the case... use firebug and see the request made to facebook. I think its always with www.

Comment: I confirm that you can set "abc.com" as your domain and use any subdomain