# facebook api error code: 191 Asp.Net MVC 3 using Dev Environment localhost and ACS

Tags: asp.net, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, azure, acs

I have been trying for the last couple of days to get the ACS integration for my identity providers.  The main ones work, Google, Yahoo!, and Live, but I cannot get Facebook to work with my localhost dev environment.  Also Facebook has changed their Apps Configuration Pages and I am confused.

Does anyone know the updated Step by Step for configuring ACS and Facebook to work together? My url is:  http://localhost/webapp1/
I have been looking through all the posts but since things have changed, the old answers do not seem to work.  I know it must be either on one of the setup pages in Azure ACS or in Facebook Apps Setup or a problem with my web.config.  I would greatly appreciate all help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook API error 191](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem when I setup ACS for Facebook and ran it from my local machine. I had erroneously setup my application on Facebook, while my [Azure ACS](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/appfabric/) configuration was actually correct. I was using 'localhost/myapp' on the **Site URL** setup field on the Facebook site but I needed to change it to use the full ***ACS namespace*** for my application: (Your specific *namespace* will vary, please check your ACS settings for details)

I noticed you mentioned that your URL was: "http://localhost/webapp1/", I am not sure if this was your specific problem but hopefully this saves someone else a bit of time.

Comment: Indeed the Facebook integration with ACS would require developer to put the **ACS namespace url** instead of the actual web application address. The reason is that all authentication requests are going to and from the ACS service, not the actual application.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (see [Facebook API error 191](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191) for an older example)

Check your domain is configured correctly in the app settings, the URL used much match what you've told Facebook you'll be using.

Comment: This does not work.  The changes to the facebook developer setup and localhost is not working.  Any one have a sample since the changes to facebook in the last week that works and a screen shot or documentation on the facebook developer pages on how you did the configuration?  It can be a test app would be fine.