# Facebook Canvas App: API Error Code: 191  : Authentication Error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-authentication, facebook-apps

I'm trying to setup a new facebook app using the example from Facebook but Authentication gives me an error.

I first go developers.facebook.com/setup/ and use the URL of my site (tried both the base and subfolder: http://mydomain.com and http://mydomain.com/facebook-app/ )

Canvas URL : http://mydomain.com/faceboo-app/
Secure Canvas URL: none

My index.php

```
<?php 


 $app_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

 $canvas_page = "http://apps.facebook.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/";

 $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
        . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page);

 $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

 list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

 $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

 if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
        echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
 } else {
        echo ("Welcome User: " . $data["user_id"]);
 }
```

?>

When I try to visit http://apps.facebook.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/

I get:

An error occurred with APP Name. Please try later

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.

Can someone please help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook API error 191](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ou have to redirect user back to your web, so your $canvas_url variable has to be your web URL (which you entered in app setup)

Comment: How i missed that :(
Thank you!
Now I'm redirected to http://domain.com/facebook/?code=dasdasdas..
caught in a redirect loop. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, i see you're parsing signed_request, i haven't tried that method, instead i just checked whether i recieved code or not ($_GET['code]', if variable is empty then you need to redirect user using your $auth_url, if it's not, you can proceed to next step of web authentification)