# 191 API Error with Facebook Connect

Tags: facebook, fbconnect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook API error 191](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191)

I'm getting a 191 error on my website when attempting to log in with Facebook Connect.

The base URL is `www.example.co.uk/section/`, but the "log in" button on the site refers to `www.example.co.uk/`.

How do I get it to refer to the `/section/` directory?

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert base url of your website as www.example.co.uk/section/ in application settings in facebook developers

Comment: How do you do that? Ive set the only URL box to www.example.co.uk/section/ but it still refers back to www.example.co.uk as thats all you can put in the domain area, or am i just missing something?