# Facebook JS SDK: FB.ui callback doesn't work - need working example code

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

When I use the Send dialog using the Facebook JS SDK FB.ui call, the callback does not trigger.

```
FB.ui(
      {
          method: 'send',
          to: ****,            // fbId 
          redirect_uri: *****, // public URL in my app domain 
          link: *****          // public URL 
      },
      function(response) {
          alert('callback was called!');
          if (response != null) {
               console.log('Request was passed along!');
               location.href= ***;    // just in case redirect_uri doesn't work
               return true;
          }
          else {
               console.log('Not passed along. User clicked cancel');
          }
      }
```

);

**Expected behavior:** The alert should be shown. The console message should be logged. And the user should be sent to the redirect_uri.

**Actual Behavior:** None of these 3 things happen. The Send dialog opens and the to: field is pre-populated correctly. When I click Send, it is sent correctly. But I need the callback to be triggered and the user needs to be sent to redirect_uri.

Comment: Hey, any chance we could get a link? This might sound stupid, but are you sure that the console is active in the browser you're using?

What happens if you console.log(response)?

Comment: Are you sure message sent correctly?

Comment: The console is active and the message is sent correctly.

Comment: This is a known bug. See: https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect/issues/118

Comment: It seems that 'redirect_uri' conflicts with callback! It works if 'redirect_uri' is not specified. But you have to specify proper 'Site URL' in application settings. Here's the great discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `redirect_uri` item and the call back will be fired.

I was facing the same issue a few mins back and realized that removing the `redirect_uri` solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Every FB.UI has a callback function and it applies to Send dialog also.

See this [document](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/) for general syntax for FB.UI.

But the problem is as other FB.UI methods, SEND method doesn't have a return value.

As per Facebook documentation ,

> **If sending the message is successful, the user will be redirected to the redirect_uri.  Otherwise, an error will be shown. Unlike the Like
>   Button, there is no return value per se.**

So if the message sending is successful and you dont have a redirect_uri then the callback will have nothing as a return value and otherwise sends error when message sending is failed.

To confirm that callback is working use the following code,

```
FB.ui({
          method: 'send',
          name: 'People Argue Just to Win',
          link: 'http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/15/arts/people-argue-just-to-win-scholars-assert.html',
          },
          function(response){
           alert(response);
           if(response != null){
            alert('user clicked send');
           }else{
            alert('user clicked cancel');
           }
          });
```

when you click send and message is sent successfully , it will alert an empty string and when u click cancel it will alert 'null'.

Comment: I used your code, but it still doesn't work. None of the alerts pop open. I also included a redirect_uri, but FB doesn't redirect there.  My website is in sandbox mode, but this shouldn't be a problem. Other solutions?

Comment: The send dialog needs the link to be an active url which is accessible to the world. For testing purpose use any publicly available domain.

Comment: Yes, the link is publicly available and in the domain specified in the FB dev app. But the user is still not sent to the redirect_uri. Other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified on other browsers? Check your browser settings once.
Do you have an extension like "[Facebook Disconnect](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ejpepffjfmamnambagiibghpglaidiec)" installed?