# Facebook authorize not working

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-canvas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook API error 191](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191)

I have an MVC facebook app.

Here is the config:

```
  <facebookSettings appId="**" appSecret="**" canvasPage="http://apps.facebook.com/fooapp/" canvasUrl="http://localhost:3262/Home/" secureCanvasUrl="https://localhost:3262/Home/" />
```

in global asax :

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Foo", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
```

By default Foo controller doesnt use authorize. But Home controller uses authorize.When i hit Foo/ it works. When i hit Home controller. i get back `An error occurred with Bingo. Please try again later.` . Essentially it s not authorizing.

What am i missing?
why this is not working?

in fb config:`http://localhost:3262/Home/` this is the canvas url.

When i hit `http://localhost:3262/Home/` manually.

i get back

`API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.`

Comment: @James this is not the same. this is a canvas app.

Comment: @DarthVadar - Error is the same though. Is it possibly an issue with using localhost instead of a valid domain name?

Comment: @James same issue on prod. not related to domain name.

Comment: Have you set `Website with Facebook Login` in your app settings to `http://localhost:3262/Home/` (or at least `http://localhost:3262/`) as well?

Comment: it s a canvas app not a website.