# Post to users wall with PHP error

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook API error 191](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191)

I have a Facebook page app running a competition entry that posts to the users wall upon entry.
I have it set up and working on my development server but when I try to host it from my dedicated server I get the error:

> API Error Code: 191 API Error Description: The specified URL is not
>   owned by the application Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given
>   URL is not permitted by the application configuration.

This suggests I haven't used the correct URL in my app settings, but I have checked and doubled checked and everything is okay. 
It only seems to be a problem when hosted on my dedicated server as I have tested the app from servers and it works fine. For this project unfortunately it HAS to be hosted from my dedicated server.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Each Facebook application requires it's own unique domain name.  One domain name for one Facebook application.

Create new application for you production domain name.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said I have already done this. I have multiple versions to test where the problem is coming from. I have tested with 3 domains / 3 facebook apps - all exactly the same (apart from the app id / app secret) 2 versions of the app work when hosted on shared hosting, the version on my dedicated server does not work