# simple tab app error 191

Tags: facebook, tabs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook API error 191](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191)

I am new to Facebook.

I am trying to put a tab on my business Facebook page.  Here is a link to the steps I followed.

```
facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/
```

when I try

```
facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL
```

I get

```
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.
```

From what I have read, I have some type of configuration problem.

Any thoughts or suggestions.

[Here](http://sbhousevalues.com/191_facebook_problem.pdf) is a link to a *PDF* file with 4 screen shots.

The basic info/tab info `Facebook` app info.

Results for [sbhousevalues_b](https://sbhousevalues.com/sbhousevalues_b/) and [sbhousevalues](https://sbhousevalues.com).

The error message.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add `sbhousevalues-com` to the 'App Domains' section of your app's basic settings.

You can access the right section by going to [developers.facebook.com](http://developers.facebook.com), clicking 'Apps', selecting your app and clicking 'Edit this app'.

Comment: thanks for your reply, if you will note from the pdf file, it is already in the apps section.  However, I may not understand how this all fits together.  Any other thoughts.