# Facebook Authentication, how to fix API Error Code: 191

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook API error 191](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191)

I want to use facebook autentication on my web site. if I test my application on the server using the real domain name, everything works.

however if I test it locally. I kept getting this error message

http:// localhost:60627/account/FacebookLogin?returnUrl=

```
Error
An error occurred with Put a straw in it. Please try again later.

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.
```

I pretty sure my code is fine, because it works on production server.  it must be the setting in facebook.

I searched on google, there are alot posts regarding this problem.

this is what I tried.

1. Sandbox mode is set to disabled. I already did this.
2. Set value for canvas URL. Mine is not app on facebook, I dont think this will work for me.
3. try to add localhost to app domains, but facebook wont let me.

please help me to figure out why I only get this message on local machine?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the domain that is set in your applications domain settings.  Only that domain can be used to make calls and authenticate.

domain settings must be a publicly facing domain, "no local host"

Local host will not work in most cases.

Comment: i need to test it before I upload it online. is there a way to test it locally?  there must be a way to do it.

Comment: i will check the documents again, and the dev forum.  I am pretty sure though that is the law of facebook apps.