# Canvas URL is not a valid URL. Secure Canvas URL is not a valid URL

Tags: php, facebook

I have configured my application on facebook and provided
Canvas URL:http://fb.kpratik.webatu.com/
Secure Canvas URL:https://fb.kpratik.webatu.com/

This was working perfectly. But since yesterday when i try to login through my application
i am getting following error:
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.

When i go back to facebook and check settings of my app i see an error saying:
Warning
Canvas URL is not a valid URL.
Secure Canvas URL is not a valid URL.

Please help

Comment: check your application config file make sure , u have same urls everywhere

Comment: I have only provided URL in Canvas URL and Secure Canvas URL.. Could you please point me to some another file/settings?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191

Answer (score 0):

> When i go back to facebook and check settings of my app i see an error saying: Warning Canvas URL is not a valid URL. Secure Canvas URL is not a valid URL.

Trying to post http://fb.kpratik.webatu.com/ on Facebook I get the message that I can’t post that URL, because the domain webatu.com is blocked because of being spammy.

You run into one of the usual problems using shared webhosting without an individual domain: Once one user of the service behaves badly, the whole domain gets blocked, and everyone else using it has to suffer the same fate too.

My advice would be – get your own domain, so that you are independent from what other people do on Facebook. If your own domain gets blocked, it’s your fault and your fault only. But you won’t get blocked for other peoples mistakes.

Comment: Thanks CBroe, So thats the only solution left, or is there any workaround for time being unless i have my own domain

Comment: CBroe, Could you please let me know how did u try post of a URL on facebook?