# grails spring security facebook redirect uri

Tags: facebook, apache, tomcat, grails, spring-security

Do we need any special configuration when running tomcat behind apache?

I have my grails app running on tomcat 8080 behind apache on port 80. When 
I do facebook login it fails with the following error:

```
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.
```

I have the following config in my
**https.conf**

```
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mydomain.com
<Proxy *>
AddDefaultCharset Off
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

**tomcat6 server.xml**

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
connectionTimeout="20000"
redirectPort="8443" />
```

facebook app config:
app domain: mydomain.com
web site url: http://mydomain.com:8080/myapp

Comment: Did you follow the steps outlined in here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191   this is going to be some type of app configuration issue.   What was your redirect URL ?

Comment: Thanks for the info - Nix. It is about Web Site URL and redirect URL mismatch that caused the issue.

Comment: So you fixed your issue?

Comment: Yes, it is fixed once web site url on facebook configuration and redirect url in my code are the same.