# How to fix "requires valid redirect URI" at Facebook Share Dialog?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, redirect, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-sharer

I am using the standard `Feed Dialog` of **Facebook** to share posts on my website. The problem with this one is that I can't get it working because of problems with the `redirect_uri`. That's very weird, because I own the app, the App ID is correct and the URL is correct... What might be the problem here? The error I get is: **Requires valid redirect URI**.

This is the code I am using:

```
<a href=https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=9999999999999&link=http://hereismylink.com/todays/&picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&name=%TITLE%&caption=testing1234&description=blablabla&redirect_uri=http://hereismylink.com>Share on Face</a>
```

PS: the redirect_uri and app_id are dummy text, normally, they are the correct numbers and letters on my site. I don't want to advertise here.

FYI: `sandbox mode` is turned off

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook API error 191](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191)

Comment: lol. It is not duplicate because these are different errors.

Comment: It is precisely the same issue, the redirect_uri does not match the app settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved it by stating the url of my page in the `app domain`. It is too bad that the Facebook documentation lacks this kind of information, because it is essential to get it to work. Anyway, thanks lgy for giving me the link.

Comment: I've noticed the Facebook documentation is quite awful.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I learned that the issue was the site being SSL. If you're seeing this problem, check out the URL that's called when the FB share box is launched as a pop-up window. That URL has to have a valid redirect_URI value at the end. You'll probably see that it's malformed in some way. That should give you some insight into where the problem lies. Sometimes the popup share window appears and disappears too quickly and you don't even get to see that "Redirect URI" error.

I've been configuring "Easy Social Share Buttons for WordPress".  I ran into this problem on several Wordpress instances after using a plugin called Restrict HTTPS. I changed the plugin to Easy SSL. Then I removed all instances of the open graph scripts being called via other plugins. That remedied the problem for me.

Check out how I have it configured now on [Massive Impressions Online Marketing.](https://www.massiveimpressions.com) If you go to one of the blog posts or portfolio posts linked at the bottom, you'll see those share buttons configured. I'm using a Facebook App for the site. I've tried a lot of share solutions, WordPress plugins and manual placement of code, and this particular plugin has been better than most, in my opinion, even compared to the buttons in Jetpack.

Good Luck!!!