# Given URL not allowed by the Application configuration

Tags: facebook-graph-api, tizen, tizen-web-app

I am developing a web application in tizen to integrate with facebook and I am getting "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains" error. I have searched a lot and I am not clear about what I have to mention in "App Domains" (I am developing app for mobile) section after getting appId. Please help me to resolve this error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook API error 191](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191)

Comment: I am developping standalone mobile application for facebook. Please tell me clearly what to place in Website with Facebook Login and appdomain. I didnt find answer to my question in the Facebook API error 191. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a Cross Domain AJAX Request problem. You have to allow the access in your config.xml file - either each url you call, or for all (*):

[image: allow access]