# Facebook login API Error Code: 191

Tags: node.js, facebook, express, passport.js

I am getting this error:

```
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.
```

When browsing to this page.

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fusers%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&scope=email%2Cuser_about_me&client_id=clientid&type=web_server

I ofcourse googled around and found this topic:

[Facebook API error 191](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191)

It says that add your page URL to facebook. I have been going through all tabs in facebook under my created App and there is no input box for page URL.

I also see that this answer is from early 2012 and possibly outdated, how should it be done in 2013?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to "http://developers.facebook.com" you should be able to login, click on "Apps" at the top. From there you can click on "Edit Settings" for the app that you are testing (or creating). I took a screen shot of what that looks like:

[image: Edit Settings Screen]

My guess is there is an error in the field "App Domains", or in the "Site URL" field. You will want to make sure that your url and domain(s) are correct. Hopefully this helps or at least sets you on the right track.

One more suggestion - it looks like you are testing using "localhost". If you are developing on a windows system you can improve the quality of your tests by [editing the hosts file](http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/windows-7-hosts-file/) and registering your actual host name. OSX or other operating systems have similar mechanisms for registering a host name. Once you have done this you can bind IIS or Apache to that host by creating a new site (or using the virtual hosts option). After that you should be able to type in a more real looking host name which makes the Facebook authentication work that much better. Best of luck!

Comment: What should I write to App domain? And where is the Site URL located, I can't seem to find a button Edit settings, there is only settings button and nowhere is input field "Site URL"..http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=of51k0&s=5

Comment: I took a screen shot of my app in the facebook developers page with the name blanked out. Does that help you in finding what you are looking for?   As far as the host settings go, look up what server are you using for testing?

Comment: When I click on apps, the apps list wont show, but a dropdown window comes, which allows me only create an app or go into specific apps.http://i41.tinypic.com/1zf3eb6.png